# PIL / urllib2 - cannot identify image file when passing file using StringIO

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, urllib2

I'm downloading an image from the web using urllib2. Once I have downloaded it I want to do some stuff with it using an image module called PIL. I don't want to save the file to disk then reopen but rather pass it from memory using `StringIO`

```
from PIL import Image

image_buff = urllib2.urlopen(url)
image = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(image_buff))
```

However when I do this I get the following error

```
IOError: cannot identify image file <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x101afa2d8
```

I think this is because I'm not passing a string but rather a urllib2 object/instance. Would anyone know how I can pass a string to PIL correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `.read()` your `urllib2.urlopen` object:

```
import StringIO
from PIL import Image

image_buff = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
image = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(image_buff))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from PIL import image
from StringIO import StringIO

f = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/some.jpg")
data = f.read()

im = Image.open(StringIO(data))
```